# CSS Container Behavior

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use #container (below) to control the height of the columns it contains. The way I have it coded doesn't seem to work. To help me identify what is going on I made the #container background-color red. I'm quite confused. Why is #container not red? What am I missing? The HTML and CSS files are below and complete. Any help is appreciated.

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
        width:1200px;
        background-color:white;
    }
    
    p{
        font-size: .7em;
        font-family:helvecta;
    }
    
    #melies-header{
        float:left;
        width:40%;
    }
    
    #container{
        width:1200px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:red;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    
    .clear {
        clear:both;
        line-height:0;
    }
    
    #menu li{
        padding-left:100px;
        display:inline;
        font-size: 1.7em;
        font-family: Bleeding Cowboys;
    }
    
    #menu li:first-child{
        margin-left:75px;
    }
    
    @font-face{
        font-family: Bleeding Cowboys;
        src: url(assets/Bleeding_Cowboys.ttf);
    }
    
    a:link{
        color:purple;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    a:hover{
        color: red;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    #header{
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 60%;
    }
    
    #header-img{
        float:left;
        margin-left:150px;
    }
    
    #header:hover{
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
        width:60%;
        img:(url)
        
    }
    
    
    #column1{
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-left:30px;
        border:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:grey;
    }
    
    #melies-portrait{
        width:300px;
    }
    
    div p {
        padding:10px;
    }
    
    #column2{
        width:300px;
        height 600px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:30px;
    }
    
    #melies-2-image{
        
    }
    
    #column3{
        width:300px;
        height:600px;
        float:left;
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
       <html>
    <head>
        <title>Archivo Melies</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="header-img"; src="images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png" 
    onmouseover="this.src='images/header-logo-950-redhover.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png'" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="filmography.html">Filmography</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-the-archive.html>About the Archive">Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        
    <div id="container">
            <div id="column1">
                <img id="melies-portrait" src="images/george_melies.jpg">
                <p>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.  </p>   
            </div>
        <div id="column2">
            <img id="melies-2-image" src="images/melies2.jpeg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>    
        </div>
        <div id="column3">
            <p>   dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i've created a demo https://fiddle.jshell.net/1hhdcyy8/, and seen that your html is mal formed. But as i readen your question, i dont understand what your needed

Comment: You have HTML errors. For example; `id "header"` -> missing `=`,
`id="header-img";` -> doesn't need for `;`.

Comment: Your last ul li a href not closed. That's why..? See below code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the final link, you are missing a `"` character after the URL.

```
<li><a href="about-the-archive.html>About the Archive</a></li>
```

Thus, all HTML from that point until the next `"` character is considered part of the `href` attribute, and not rendered on the page - it just so happens that your `#container` div is directly after it.

Once you fix it, your div will appear red. This was not a problem with your CSS at all!

```
<li><a href="about-the-archive.html">About the Archive</a></li>
```

**This is not the only problem in your source code**. Make sure that you always watch out for basic typos such as this one.

In most text editors (even in JSFiddle), all of the code from where you miss a character is syntax-highlighted red to let you know that you've missed something and alert you to the problem. You can also use your web browser's debug tools to look at the underlying page structure and notice this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TreeBeing If you feel that this is the correct answer, please mark it as accepted (by using the tick icon to the right of it in a few minutes) or upvoting it so that other people who have a similar problem can find the correct solution. I'm glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width:1200px;
    background-color:white;
}

p{
    font-size: .7em;
    font-family:helvecta;
}

#melies-header{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

#container{
    width:1200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    line-height:0;
}

#menu li{
    padding-left:100px;
    display:inline;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: Bleeding Cowboys;
}

#menu li:first-child{
    margin-left:75px;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: Bleeding Cowboys;
    src: url(assets/Bleeding_Cowboys.ttf);
}

a:link{
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    color: red;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header{
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

#header-img{
    float:left;
    margin-left:150px;
}

#header:hover{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:60%;
    img:(url)

}


#column1{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-left:30px;
    border:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:grey;
}

#melies-portrait{
    width:300px;
}

div p {
    padding:10px;
}

#column2{
    width:300px;
    height 600px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

#melies-2-image{

}

#column3{
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;

}
```

```html
<div id "header">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="header-img"; src="images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/header-logo-950-redhover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png'" />
    </a>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="filmography.html"></a>Filmography</a></li>
    <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></a></li>
    <li><a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
    <li><a href="about-the-archive.html">About the Archive</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="container">
        <div id="column1">
            <img id="melies-portrait" src="images/george_melies.jpg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.  </p>   
        </div>
    <div id="column2">
        <img id="melies-2-image" src="images/melies2.jpeg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>    
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
        <p>   dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I scoured the code multiple times looking for typos, but I guess sometimes you just can't see them? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors in your html. Now this is working.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width:1200px;
    background-color:white;
}

p{
    font-size: .7em;
    font-family:helvecta;
}

#melies-header{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

#container{
    width:1200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    line-height:0;
}

#menu li{
    padding-left:100px;
    display:inline;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: Bleeding Cowboys;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="header-img" src="images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/header-logo-950-redhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/header-logo-950-purplelink.png'" />
    </a>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="filmography.html">Filmography</a></li>
    <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
 <li><a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
    <li><a href="about-the-archive.html">About the Archive</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container">
        <div id="column1">
            <img id="melies-portrait" src="images/george_melies.jpg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.  </p>   
        </div>
    <div id="column2">
        <img id="melies-2-image" src="images/melies2.jpeg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>    
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
        <p>   dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```